Cyberduck CLI - synchronize with upload flag
I'm looking to backup a drive to an S3 bucket from a script on a Windows machine. I wondered if I could use Cyberduck's CLI to synchronize folders to S3, using the 'upload' option (of Cybduck's synchronize method).
I can execute it from a command line, but it's interactive (I'm required to tell it what to do about files it finds already in the bucket).

Use the --existing and --assumeyes flags.

Thank you, that did it (don't think I need assumeyes, --existing seems enough)!

You probably don't want another challenge, but I have this open Cyberduck/S3 question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79117456/cyberduck-cli-set-storage-class
