Cyberduck CLI - set storage class
I'm trying to synchronize files from Windows to an S3 bucket using Cyberduck CLI. I'd like to set the storage class to Glacier Instrant Retrieval. I'm attempting to do this:
set "s3.storage.class=GLACIER_IR" & duck --username XXXX1234YYYYZZZZ --synchronize s3:/my-backups/ 'backups/' --existing upload

I guessed the "s3.storage.class=GLACIER_IR" bit by looking in a config file from UI version of Cyberduck.
When I run this I see the set command execute, the folders are synchronized, but files uploaded to S3 end up ass Standard storage class.
Maybe I should just do this with AWS CLI?!

Setting the storage class to apply in the environment as given in your question should work when you additionally pass the --preserve argument.

Thanks very much for your help - I can't get that --preserve argument (which I'm assuming applies to the duck command) to make any difference though. If I add --verbose I see that that  PUT request for a file upload still has x-amz-storage-class: STANDARD

It will  preserve the storage class if you overwrite an existing file.
